# Interpretation of Neural Network (CNN) Result / Accuracy

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, tensorflow

I'm kind of new to the subject and build a convolutional neural network based on google's tensorflow. I wanted to classify a test data set of pictures belonging to 10 categories. My CNN setup is aligned to the tensorflow tutorial with some amendmends to meet my images' size. 
I ran the trainig step repeatedly for 20 times over a random sample of 500 images and then repeated that step for 50 times on different samples of size 500. I used a sample of 200 as validation data set (kept this fixed for all runs). As a result I got an accuracy of about 35%, which isn't to bad in my eyes, since I didn't do any optimizations and the images are kind of hard to assign to a single category evan for humans.

So here are my questions:

- Does it really make sense to run a step for 20 times over the same batch? (I did this becuase it's about what fits in the RAM and loading a new batch took quite a while - so I could get more runs in less time)
- In the training accuracy diagram (see below) there's a jump at some point around step 120-130. From there on the accuracy goes up close to 100% for each 20-run of the same random batch. What does that jump mean in terms of network structure / learning?

[image: Test and Training Accuracy Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

Your spikes are likely due to the network overfitting on the batch that you are repeatedly showing it, while not really learning something that is useful in general. This also answers your first question - in this case, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your points do absolutely make sense to me. Nevertheless it seemed to me that my setup (repeat 20) made sense and the network was improving as expected until step 130 without overfitting. Am I misinterpreting something here? And what happend to the net at step 130, so that it changed it's behaviour so abruptly?